# Add to homescreen

Tags: android, ios

I've been looking for best practices where to put additional link "Add to homescreen". We need to implement it while the user logs in or has just logged in.
I do not want to use a pop-up to make it so important for the user as we are not a "rude" website. I was wondering if this is a good practice if I put a small button under the Remember password for those who just wants to open our website a little bit faster.

Comment: IT might help us to understand your particular use-case if you could include some more details. I know I'm curious about what your users my want to "Add to homescreen", what form the homescreen takes (that it allows things to be added/removed), what sort of mechanic you plan to use for the adding process, and what sort of on-boarding procedures you already have - these things all seem to play a part in suggesting what you might be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about making user add your website to their home screen directly from the login page then you can try the following designs which don't really force user to add the website to their home screen

**First Variation with a catchy attractive sentence**

[image]

**Or you can try this float button notification** 
[image]